Django: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'dotenv'
I see hundreds with this issue, but the answers to other posts aren't working for me.
I'm simply trying to use dotenv and an .env file to hide sensitive data like an email password.
I've tried this and it didn't work:
pip uninstall dotenv
pip uninstall python-dotenv
pip install python-dotenv

Error Traceback:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\PythonProjects\VoterSay7\venv\lib\site- 
packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 412, in 
run_from_argv
self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
File "C:\PythonProjects\VoterSay7\venv\lib\site- 
packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", 
line 74, in execute
super().execute(*args, **options)
File "C:\PythonProjects\VoterSay7\venv\lib\site- 
packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 458, in 
execute
output = self.handle(*args, **options)
File "C:\PythonProjects\VoterSay7\venv\lib\site- 
packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", 
line 81, in handle
if not settings.DEBUG and not settings.ALLOWED_HOSTS:
File "C:\PythonProjects\VoterSay7\venv\lib\site- 
packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 102, in __getattr__
self._setup(name)
File "C:\PythonProjects\VoterSay7\venv\lib\site- 
packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 89, in _setup
self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
File "C:\PythonProjects\VoterSay7\venv\lib\site- 
packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 217, in __init__
mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)
File 

return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1030, in _ 
gcd_import
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _ 
find_and_load
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _ 
find_and_load_unlocked
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 680, in _ 
load_unlocked
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 850, in 
exec_module
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 228, in _ 
call_with_frames_removed
File "C:\Users\mattk\Box\WeConsent\VoterSay10\settings.py", 
line 14, in <module>
import dotenv
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'dotenv'

from settings.py:
import dotenv
from dotenv import load_dotenv


did you activate your enviroment?

Yes. I used path\to\venv\Scripts\Activate. I also verified that python-dotenv is installed:
C:\Users\mattk\Box\WeConsent\venv>pip install 
python-dotenv
Requirement already satisfied: python-dotenv in 
c:\pythonprojects\votersay10\venv\lib\site- 
packages (1.0.1)

